# Decorator NameError

Tags: python, python-decorators

Consider this simple decorator demo:

```
class DecoratorDemo():

    def _decorator(f):
        def w( self ) :
            print( "now decorated")
            f( self )
        return w

    @_decorator
    def bar( self ) :
        print ("the mundane")

d = DecoratorDemo()
d.bar()
```

Running this gives the expected output:

```
now decorated
the mundane
```

The type for `d.bar` and `d._decorator` confirm as `<class 'method'>` if I add the following two lines to the end of above code.

```
print(type(d.bar))
print(type(d._decorator))
```

Now if i modify the above code to define `bar` method before defining the `_decorator` method, I get the error

```
     @_decorator
NameError: name '_decorator' is not defined
```

Why is it that the ordering of the methods is relevant in the above case ?

Comment: Why wouldn't it be? A class body is executable code, which like all code is processed top to bottom.

Comment: In the same way that you have to define the decorator before decorating a function in the module, you have to define it before decorating a method in the class. Remember that the `@` is just syntactic sugar for `thing = decorator(thing)`.

Comment: The question is not as stupid as it seems. Many languages allow you to refer to things only defined later in certain cases. In fact, even in Python you are allowed to "call" a not yet defined method in a function implementation (because the call is resolved at runtime). Understanding when and when not you have to define before referring is not trivial nor pointless.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the decorated method is not actually a 'method declaration' as it seems. What the decorator syntax suger hides is this:

```
def bar( self ) :
    print ("the mundane")
bar = _decorator(bar)
```

If you put these lines before the definition of `_decorator`, the name error doesn't come as a surprise. Like @Daniel Roseman  said, the class body is just code, that is executed top to bottom.